# order solution and data import using crm package deployer

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to import multiple solutions and data files related to each solution in a CRM online instance using package deployer.
I want to order the imports as mentioned below -
Step1 - Import Solution1
Step2 - Import Data File1
Step3 - Import Solution2
Step4 - Import data File2

Please let me know how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to interleave the import of solution files and data files in a single packager deployer package given the structure defined by the [ImportConfig.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-packages-package-deployer#Step4) file which the solution packager uses to define the solutions and data files to import. The solutions will first be imported in sequential order, followed by all the data files in sequential order.

In practice, there shouldn't be a need to import the solutions and data files in such an interleaved order, and the data files can be imported after all the solutions have been imported without any issue.

If it's absolutely necessary to import the solution and data files in such an interleaved order, one could create multiple packages, with each package containing the single solution and its associated data file, and import each package one after the other in the desired order.